# Spring access global value from JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, service

In my Spring application I wish to add a configurable system message that can be displayed on every page. For example "The system is going down in 10 minutes".

I need to store this value globally, but I can't add any code to the controllers, as I don't want to have to change every single one of them. I thought of using a @Service, but I don't know how I can access this directly from the JSP.

I'm happy to use JSP scriptlet notation to get what I need. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another idea would be to put the messages in the application scope?
Many people are not aware that there is one more scope other than request, session, and page.

At the servlet, set the attribute (request is a HttpServletRequest object passed to doGet/doPost method):

```
request.getSession().getServletContext()
    .setAttribute("my.sys.msg", "The system is going down in 10 minutes.");
```

In your JSP file use something like this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="my.sys.msg" scope="application" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with a properties file. in order to do that, place a file called messages.properties under your WEB-INF/classes folder with this content:

```
shutdown=The system is going down in 10 minutes.
```

then you have to include the necesssary information in your servlet-context.xml file so that it can look for the messages in the correct file:

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/classes/messages />
        <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
```

and finally you can reference that message from your jsp for example using the formatting tag library from JSTL:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<fmt:message key="shutdown"/>
```

Comment: With this solution I'd have to edit the messages.properties on the server, and it would update the message?

Comment: yes, you'd only have to update the messages.properties because all your jsp pages would call the same message in that file everytime you load a page.